# UnrecoverableKeyException caused by obscure KeyStoreException: 112

Tags: android, android-keystore

I'm seeing this in my crash logs a lot when prompting the fingerprint dialog to authenticate the user.

```
java.security.UnrecoverableKeyException: Failed to obtain information about key at 
..my code..
io.reactivex.internal.operators.observable.ObservableObserveOn$ObserveOnObserver.checkTerminated(ObservableObserveOn.java:287) at 
    io.reactivex.internal.operators.observable.ObservableObserveOn$ObserveOnObserver.drainNormal(ObservableObserveOn.java:172) at 
    io.reactivex.internal.operators.observable.ObservableObserveOn$ObserveOnObserver.run(ObservableObserveOn.java:255) at 
    io.reactivex.android.schedulers.HandlerScheduler$ScheduledRunnable.run(HandlerScheduler.java:119) at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873) at 
    android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) at 
    android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214) at 
    android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6981) at 
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) at 
    com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493) at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1445) 
Caused by: java.security.UnrecoverableKeyException: Failed to obtain information about key at 
    android.security.keystore.AndroidKeyStoreProvider.getKeyCharacteristics(AndroidKeyStoreProvider.java:238) at 
    android.security.keystore.AndroidKeyStoreProvider.loadAndroidKeyStoreKeyFromKeystore(AndroidKeyStoreProvider.java:360) at 
    android.security.keystore.AndroidKeyStoreSpi.engineGetKey(AndroidKeyStoreSpi.java:116) at java.security.KeyStore.getKey(KeyStore.java:1062) at 
Caused by: android.security.KeyStoreException: 112 at 
    android.security.KeyStore.getKeyStoreException(KeyStore.java:1147) at 
    android.security.keystore.AndroidKeyStoreProvider.getKeyCharacteristics(AndroidKeyStoreProvider.java:240) ... 34 more
```

What is this KeystoreException: 112, and what would cause this? I'm trying to organically reproduce the error, but haven't been able to.

Comment: "112" and "System error" are the two which have stumped us more than anything else.